# The number of integral points in a polytope

Tags: approximation-algorithms, polytope

Suppose we define a polytope with 
$$
\mathbf{Ax} \leq  \mathbf{b} 
$$
What is the best way to find/approximate the number of the integral points in the polytope? 
Update: how hard is the complexity of this problem?

Update: dimension of the space is $n$ and is a variable in the problem.

Comment: Maybe you know this, but let me mention that it's NP-hard because the IP feasibility problem is NP-hard.

Comment: I think counting the solutions is #P-complete. You can encode the permanent of a 0-1 matrix as such a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Check out

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/

and the corresponding paper

Effective lattice point counting in rational convex polytopes. Jesús A. De Loera, Raymond Hemmecke, Jeremiah Tauzer, Ruriko Yoshida. Journal of Symbolic Computation 2004 38:4, 1273-1302.

The algorithm they implement was introduced in

A Polynomial Time Algorithm for Counting Integral Points in Polyhedra When the Dimension is Fixed. Alexander I. Barvinok. Mathematics of Operations Research 1994 19:4, 769-779.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the *parameterized complexity* of the counting problem is still open. It is known that *ILP solving* is fixed-parameter tractable in the number of variables ('Integer programming with a fixed number of variables', H.W.Lenstra Jr), although *ILP solution counting* is expected to be $\# W[1]$-hard. The question was first asked by N. Betzler if my memory is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Beside Latte, there is a less famous tool, called Barvinok (name of the original author of the algorithm):
http://freecode.com/projects/barvinok

The algorithm is described in this paper:

Sven Verdoolaege, Rachid Seghir, Kristof Beyls, Vincent Loechner, Maurice Bruynooghe: *Counting Integer Points in Parametric Polytopes Using Barvinok's Rational Functions*. Algorithmica 48(1): 37-66 (2007)

As far as I know, Latte can't handle parametric polytopes like Barvinok.